# Как правильно создать метод для открытия txt файла?

Tags: java

**Device.java**

```
    public void saveProject(String name) {                    //Сохранение проекта в .txt
        Directory current = firstDir;
        File file = new File(name);

        try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
             PrintStream printStream1 = new PrintStream(fileOutputStream)) {
            System.setOut(printStream1);
            while (current != null) {
                System.out.println(current.getNameDir() + " ");
                current.display();
                current = current.getNextDir();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void openProject(String name) {              //Открытиек проекта
        File file = new File(name);

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
            }
            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**консольный вывод**

```
  Dir1 
Имя файла : file1  Размер файла: 5442
Имя файла : file1  Размер файла: 5343
Имя файла : file1  Размер файла: 5434
Имя файла : file1  Размер файла: 4535
Кол-во элементов: 4  Длина массива: 4
Объем файлов 20754 Кбайт
Dir2 
Имя файла : file1  Размер файла: 4236
Имя файла : file1  Размер файла: 4237
Имя файла : file1  Размер файла: 8432
Имя файла : file1  Размер файла: 4239
Кол-во элементов: 4  Длина массива: 4
Объем файлов 21144 Кбайт
```

Помогите с методами сохранения и открытия файла. Метод сохранения я реализовал и он сохраняет а загрузка выполнена неправильно, т.к. в дальнейшем программа будет реализована в оконном виде и требуется, чтобы было сохранение и загрузка работы программа.

### Замечания преподавателя по поводу программы

**Класс Устройство:**

- добавление: ЕЩЕ РАЗ повторяю, что добавляемый объект надо создавать
              ТОЛЬКО тогда, когда это действительно надо (когда найдено место           вставки)
- открытие проекта это не вывод на консоль, а восстановление объектной структуры в памяти

Comment: Вы выложили весь код, а проблема с одним методом. Попробуйте на нем сконцентрироваться. Распишите подробно что он должен делать и что именно у Вас не получается.

Comment: @defaultlocale как я могу реализовать правильно методы сохранения и загрузки работы программы.Просто потом я буду подключать gui и чтобы нажав на кнопку я мог сохранить объект и загрузить обратно.

Comment: Понятно. Неясно какой объект Вы хотите получать и в каком виде он должен храниться. Распишите это как можно подробнее. И уберите, пожалуйста, не имеющий отношения к вопросу код.

Comment: @defaultlocale сверху я выложил результаты работы программы в консоли.А когда я буду это делать в оконной программе,как я могу написать метод который будет сохранять и так же загружать обратно не теряя объектную структуру

Answer (score 0):

> как я могу написать метод который будет сохранять и так же загружать обратно не теряя объектную структуру

Какая конкретная структура нужна неясно, но думаю Вам нужно получить методы примерно с такой сигнатурой:

```
public void saveProject(String name, Project project) {
     ...
}


public Project openProject(String name) {
```

Вместо `Project` подставьте имя своего класса, который будет содержать все данные нужные для сохранения. Если у Вас есть несколько объектов, то можно передать в методы массив или список.

**Проблема:** Сейчас каждый класс пишет сам себя в консоль. Соответственно, функции сохранения раскиданы по нескольким местам и смешаны с функциями отображениями.

**Решение:** Перенести всю работу с файлами в `Device`. Все методы в `Directory` которые выводят в консоль заменить на методы, возвращающие данные, и обращаться к ним из `Device`.

В `saveProject` Вы будете проходить по всем полям и писать их в файл. Примерный код:

```
for(Directory directory : project.getDirectories()) {
    out.println(directory.getName());
    //... другие поля
}
```

Рекомендую использовать [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) для записи файлов, а не переопределять стандартный вывод (он пригодится для других целей, например, отладки).

В `openProject` нужно будет читать файл, разбирать строки и создавать объекты.

Так Вы отделите открытие/сохранение проекта в файл от его отображения. После этого если потребуется изменить отображение на вывод в окне класс `Device` не потребуется менять.

Как видите изменений придется сделать довольно много, при этом требования к классам и формату сохранения известны только Вам, т.ч. навряд ли можно дать точный ответ. Но общее направление должно быть понятно: постарайтесь вносить изменения пошагово, например, сначала сохранить одно поле, затем его прочитать  затем один объект, затем список и т.д.